# I want to integrate Apple Pay into my app. Do Apple look after the receiving payment side of things?

Tags: ios, integration, payment-gateway, applepay

I have integrated apple pay into my iOS app and it works within a test environment. But now I want to be able to receive the payments into my business account when users pay via my app. I have contacted Apple twice but have not received a reply.

So my question is do Apple set up the server-side of things so that once a payment is processed that it gets paid into my business account? Or do I need to do this myself?

Answer (score 2):

Apple is not responsible to provide you with server side solution to process payments.

You can either create your own payment processing solution or use third party payment providers such as [Stripe](https://stripe.com/ca?&utm_campaign=paid_brand&utm_medium=cpc&utm_source=google&ad_content=301544840306&utm_term=stripe&utm_matchtype=e&utm_adposition1t1&utm_device=m&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIndyKsLfX4AIVBAlpCh2JRwSvEAAYASAAEgIufPD_BwE), [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com/ca), etc. Apple recommends that you use third party provider as it can get complicated dealing with credit/debit card authorization and payments.

From documentation:

> Using an SDK or JS API from a payment provider that supports Apple Pay is highly recommended.

I strongly recommend that you check Apple Pay’s documentation and understand before completing implementation. Below is the link to documentation:

[Getting started with Apple Pay](https://developer.apple.com/apple-pay/get-started/)